# Apparent race condition in JQuery / Chrome

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to add up the sizes of some li / a elements to get the size of all of them (which is different from the ul), like this:

```
$("ul.menu").children("li").children("a").each(function () {
    menuWidth += $(this).innerWidth();  
});
```

Right after that, I want to add the border width between each element, without double-counting any (probably better ways of doing this).

```
menuWidth += numberOfBorders * borderThickness;
```

When I check what the output of menuWidth is, some of the time it's the correct size 912 (898 + 16, the borders). Other times it's 970 (954 + 16). I can't get my head around what's causing this, except that maybe some race condition weirdness because of the `each()` function or something with Chrome. From my peremptory search I see a lot of results saying js/jquery isn't multithreaded or something, but that seems rather dubious to me. Any ideas? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Edit: 
**More background:**

I'm trying to do some semi-kludgey css styling via JQuery instead of getting everything perfectly sized, positioned, etc. using css. In this case I'm trying to get a menu's size, and, after finding the window's size, to expand / reduce the menu size by adding padding-left / right to the interior menu links. I'm sure there's probably a conventional way to do this in CSS, but at this point I'm really curious why this seemingly simple thing doesn't seem to work consistently. I've tried getting rid of all images in the site, Google Fonts, or anything else that could possibly be asynchronous but no luck yet. At this point I'm a little suspicious that it might have to do with Wordpress.

Comment: Are you using font-face in CSS?

Comment: I can guarantee you the issue is not a race condition within JS as `each()` is a synchronous call. It may be caused by some CSS styling  being applied or `img` elements expanding as your page loads though. Try running the code under `$(window).on('load', fn)`. To give you a more exact answer we would need to see a more complete example of your code.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I'm using Google Fonts (through `@import`), so I guess maybe the answer is 'yes'

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thanks for the tip of trying putting it in the `on('load')`. That seems to have made it a little more consistent (the 'wrong' value unfortunately, with maybe every 1/10 being the 'correct'  one). My code is a little convoluted at this point so I don't want to subject anyone to scouring it for me. I'll clean things up and poke around some more in the meantime. Also, for what it's worth, I'm using Wordpress and its script enqueuing function.